# I don't have access to Adding attribute in default property of IdentityUser

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to use attribute added to the IdentityUser default property but icant.

**Strtup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            // Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
       }
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) 
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

}
```

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int Coin { get; set; }
}
```

in this class , i cant change value of the coin

coin is a Adding attribute in default property of IdentityUser 
**AccountController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;


    public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager
        ,
        IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings,
        ApplicationDbContext db
        //IEmailSender emailsender
        )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signManager = signInManager;
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        _db = db;
    }
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterViewModel formdata)
    {
        var errorList = new ErrorLoginReg();
        var user = new IdentityUser
        {
            Email = formdata.Email,
            UserName = formdata.UserName,
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, formdata.Password);
        Dictionary<string, string> styleError = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Customer");
            var dbUser = _db.Users.Where(a => a.Id == user.Id).First();
            dbUser.Coin =1500; //Error
             _db.Users.Update(dbUser);

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(new { success=true, username = user.UserName, email = user.Email, status = 1, message = "Registration Successful" });

        }
        else
        {
            errorList.success = false;

            List<errormodel> deserror = new List<errormodel>();
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                styleError.Add(error.Code, error.Description);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                var ermo = new errormodel();
                ermo.code = error.Code;
                ermo.message = error.Description;
                deserror.Add(ermo);
            }
            errorList.error = deserror;

        }

        return Json(errorList);

    }
```

I don't have access to Coin in AccountController !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have access to Coin in AccountController !

It isn't there because you haven't actually instructed Identity to use your ApplicationUser class instead of your IdentityServer class.

Three things need to happen

- the database context needs to know about your ApplicationUser class. So you change your context to:

```cs
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

- the call to addIdentity needs to use the ApplicationUser class as well

```cs
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => { .. });
```

- the database should be expanded with the Coin column by adding a migration after the previous changes and then updating the database.

```cs
> add-migration add_coin_to_user -c ApplicationDbContext

> update-database -c ApplicationDbContext
```

**Edit:**
Any services depending on IdentityUser should also take the same TKey as what you used to register the services in startup.

- That means changing

`private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;`

to `private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;`

and so forth for every service that takes the IdentityUser.

Comment: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'MrCoach.Controllers.AccountController'.

Comment: @hamid I forgot to mention you need to change the dependent services' TKey as well